# "Getting An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected" error with my query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic

I get the error when I pass this query to my proc that execute dynamic sql:

```
"select @display =  @display + gp2.ProblemDesc  + ''|' '
from (SELECT gp.GrantProblemID, gp.ProblemDesc, gps.GrantProblemStatus, row_number() over (partition by gp.grantproblemid order by p.periodid desc) ranking 
from MergedProgressReport.dbo.[PeriodAgencyGrantProblems] pagp    
inner join MergedProgressReport.dbo.PeriodAgencyGrants pag on pag.PeriodAgencyGrantsID = pagp.PeriodAgencyGrantID 
and pag.GrantNumber =  ''2011UMWX0001''   
inner join MergedProgressReport.dbo.periodagencyinfo pai on pag.PeriodAgencyInfoID = pai.PeriodAgencyInfoID   
inner join MergedProgressReport.dbo.Periods p on p.PeriodID = pai.PeriodID   
inner join MergedProgressReport.dbo.GrantProblemStatus gps on pagp.GrantProblemStatusID = gps.GrantProblemStatusID  
inner join MergedProgressReport.dbo.GrantProblems gp on pagp.GrantProblemID = gp.GrantProblemID 
and gp.GrantProblemAreaID = 7) xx right join MergedProgressReport.dbo.GrantProblems gp2 on xx.GrantProblemID = gp2.GrantProblemID and xx.ranking = 1 
where gp2.GrantProblemAreaID = 7 "
```

My proc:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[Review_Get_PrePopValue](@sqlQuery nvarchar(500), @display nvarchar(200) OUTPUT)
as

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery,   
      N'@display varchar(200) output', 
      @display = @display output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, my parameter @sqlQuery nvarchar(500) was too small, it truncated my sql statement in my proc..Just resized it to 3000.